# How to uninstall all specific related packages in one command?

Tags: grep, npm, uninstallation, package.json

I have a lot of grunt packages in package.json. How to uninstall them in one command?
Something like npm uninstall and some grep?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I did it one by one but for future would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do -- are you aiming to reinstall the packages, or are they no longer dependencies of your project?

Generally what I do if I have made non-trivial changes to `package.json` is:

`rm -fr node_modules
npm install`

This deletes the currently-installed dependencies and re-installs only the dependencies (and devDependencies) specified by the current package.json.

Comment: They are no longer dependencies. 
Your proposal is good. I thought about something with grep because they all start with grunt-*. Thanks!